# Django, get_absolute_url method for file object

Tags: django, url, absolute

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/uploads/%i" % self.id
```

It's not what I want but
This is far as I can think of. I need a link for my files (like.../**photo.jpg**)

I just learned how to get feeds from my django website.
And I want this jpeg's absolute url.

http://myDjangoWeb/uploads/goodies_89087_1211864024_1.jpeg

How can I get this file's absolute url.....self.?????

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just use `.url` property of the file field.

See ["Managing files"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/) in Django documentation.

Comment: Amazing. It's like this "return self.image.url" Thanks.